# mount img file with fstab

Tags: linux, mount

I have an img file. I mount it using this command

```
mount -o loop,offset=70254592 image/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img /mnt/raspberry-rootfs
```

But I must do that every time I power up my computer. 
Is there a method to mount it using the fstab file?

I don't know what to put in the system type. I tried iso9660 and ext4 but this doesn't work.
The `fdisk -l` command gives me this output:

```
Disk 2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img: 1,3 GiB, 1386217472 bytes, 2707456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x84f9d19f

Device                               Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img1        8192  137215  129024   63M  c W95 FAT3
2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img2      137216 2707455 2570240  1,2G 83 Linux
```

Comment: what is the result of ` mount |grep rapsberry ` when you have mounted manualy ?

Comment: @Archemar, it gives ext4 `/home/mdababi/Bureau/Tools/image/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img on /mnt/raspberry-rootfs type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: will it mount if you use ' mount -o loop,offset=70254592 -t ext4 image/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-lite.img /mnt/raspberry-rootfs' (please note ` -t ext4 ` ) ?

Comment: yes this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like img is a two part, vfat and ext4.

I would try

```
/path/to.img /mount/point ext4 loop,offset=70254592 2 0
```

with

- `/path/to.img being` /home/mdababi/Bureau/Tools/image/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie-‌​lite.img
- `/mount.point` /mnt/raspberry-rootfs

depending on your need, you may add read-only (`ro`) flag as well on fourth field.

edit: replace 0 with 2 in fifth field, thus mount will be tried once all other directories are mounted.

Comment: unfortunatly, this doesn't work. When i reboot my computer, it enter in emergency mode.

Comment: try without loop option.

Comment: no it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use parallel mount! Your system uses parallel mount for all devices, so it tries to mount /path/... when /path/... isn't mounted yet.

Comment: @IporSircer , I understand the problem now. I know that the kernel mounts the racine / read only and then starts the init process (SysVinit startup). So when the /path is mounted ?