# when mounting an .img via fstab, it shows duplicate in file manager (Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3)?

Tags: fstab, nautilus, disk-image, ubuntu-mate, caja

I have done [these procedures](https://unixcop.com/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-disk-in-ubuntu/) to mount my .img file in `/etc/fstab` (for ubuntu mate 20.04 x64)

[Create `.img` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182938/266428):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.img bs=1024 count=2M
sudo mkfs.ext4 filename.img
```

Note: also be done with gparted with [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/672860/828892)

**The problem:**

[Mount `/etc/fstab`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326537/266428) in `/mount/point`:

```
/home/user/filename.img /home/user/vdisk ext4 defaults 0 0
# or
/home/user/filename.img /home/user/vdisk ext4 loop 0 0
# or
/home/user/filename.img /home/user/vdisk auto loop 0 0
```

But always show 2 units: vdisk (mount) and loop (not mount) (see image)

[image]

if i try to click on this other drive showing unmounted i get the following message:

[image]

Why doesn't it just show the fileimage.img image mounted in the vdisk folder?

**I would like you to help me fix the `fstab` line so that two units do not appear when mounting `.img` but only one**

**Update:**

if I run any of the following commands:

```
sudo mount -a
# or
sudo mount /home/user/vdisk
```

The same thing that I describe in my post appears.

My fstab (I have altered the UUID for security reasons):

```
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9f92d1aa-458d-441a-b349-abcdefghijkl /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=F798-ABCD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile          none            swap    sw              0       0
/home/user/filename.img /home/user/vdisk ext4 defaults 0 0
```

List:

```
sudo losetup --list | grep filename.img
/dev/loop8     0      0    1  0 /home/user/filename.img   0     512
```

**Important:**

But, if I remove the `/etc/fstab` line, delete `/dev/loop8` and mount `.img` image manually (with the followings commands), the described error does not appear

```
sudo mount -o loop /home/user/filename.img /home/user/disk
# or
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop /home/user/filename.img /home/user/disk
```

**Workaround:**

1. manually

mount `.img` manually to `/dev/loopXX` available:

```
losetup -f
/dev/loop8
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop8 filename.img
sudo losetup -l
/dev/loop8         0      0         0  0 /home/user/filename.img                            0     512
```

edit `/etc/fstab` and put the line:

```
# /path/to/loop/device       /path/to/mount/point       auto       loop       0 0
# example:
/dev/loop8 /home/user/disk ext4      defaults      0 0
```

and:

`sudo mount -a`

Note: this method is not permanent

2. bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -o loop /home/user/filename.img /home/user/disk

# sudo crontab -e
@reboot ./mount-img.sh
```

Another bash to mount/umount `.img` [HERE](https://gitlab.com/maravento/gateproxy/-/raw/master/conf/scr/add/vdiskini.sh) (can be programmed in crontab to start with the system)

3. with `bindfs`:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk
# edit fstab and add line:
/home/user/filename.img /mnt/disk ext4    defaults  0   0
sudo mount -a
sudo -u user bindfs -n /mnt/disk /home/user/disk
```

**Summary:**

- There is no error
- The image is mounted (manually and with fstab)

**About mount:**

When mounting the `.img` in `fstab`, it appears **duplicated** (one is mounted and the other is not). This does not happen when mounting the `.img` manually or `/dev/loopXX` in `fstab`

**Update New:**

This appears to be a bug in Ubuntu Mate 20.04.3. In Ubuntu version 20.04.3 this problem is not present.

**testing file managers:**

affects:

- caja
- nemo
- thunar

does not affect:

- dolphin
- nautilus

[image]

[launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1945228)

[github issue](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues/1559)

[Reference](https://www.maravento.com/2018/03/disco-virtual.html)

Comment: When you reboot the machine, I would expect it to be mounted (which should be checked with `sudo mount`), I don't care what a GUI might say about it. What happens if you try running `sudo mount /home/user/vdisk`? (check with `sudo mount` after the fact).

Comment: Maybe you can try `loop,noauto`, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @eftshift0 It isn't necessary to use `sudo mount` to see the mounted file systems. That can be just run as a regular user.

Comment: mount: only root user can do this. Anyway, the question is about fstab and not about mount

Comment: @ajcg I know what the question is about. I was replying to a comment on using `mount` to view the mounted file systems which is in regard to the question. You do not need to be in a root shell to run `mount` on its own to see the mounted file systems. That can be done as a regular user across virtually every Unix-like OS including Linux (including Ubuntu), BSD, and Solaris. A root shell is only needed to use `mount` to actually mount file systems so your comment simply isn't true.

Comment: Ok, but I always use `mount` command with sudo or root account. But this is not a big problem (related to question). It can be solved with something like that `sudo mount -o loop,rw,sync filename.img mountpoint && sudo chown $USER:$USER mountpoint && sudo chmod 777 mountpoint`. and work fine with user no-root. But the problem still in fstab

Comment: One thing that you can do is to look at the boot log as it will show you what's happening while it's trying to mount the image file. You can then use that to determine why it's not mounting.

Comment: who shows that error? on fedora did the same(fstab and all that) and device notifier didn't catch anything(expected), but in Dolphin it shows like ejectable drive, even shows source file instead of loop device(which is more correct but less convenient). if you made partitions in that file then fstab file is wrong. and with partitions it may show more than one volume it can be a bit messy

Comment: I have not said that there is any error. What I am saying is that when I use fstab two units appear (see image in post) and they do not appear when I mount the .img manually. So I want to fix the fstab line and that's the help I'm asking for

Comment: Do you want to mount one particular image file, or do you want to use this mount mechanism via fstab for 'any' image file?

Comment: @sudodus both are useful to me

Comment: Short answer: for 'any' image file I suggest that you use `kpartx`. It can manage also images with [several] partitions. See [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347700/failed-to-read-last-sector-when-trying-to-mount-dd-file/1347723#1347723). I have never tried to mount an image via fstab, but I can do some testing, and I will return to you, when I have some results (maybe tomorrow because it is getting late here) ...

Comment: @sudodus `kpartx`, it is excellent but to mount the permanent image (mount at system startup) I have to use udev rules. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65756/266428 (which is more complicated. It would be easier, as I explained, that is, create a bash script that mounts the image and program it in crontab to start with the system)

Answer (score 1):

### Loop mount of simple image file via `/etc/fstab'

In a test system of Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS I created an image file similar to yours,

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=file.img bs=1M count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 5.90297 s, 178 MB/s
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 file.img
[sudo] password for tester: 
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 256000 4k blocks and 64000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: bbf0ad05-d48b-4b0c-b7e5-ea4e5959b78b
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

I created a mount point,

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/lp0
```

and **added the following line at the tail end of `/etc/fstab`**

```
/home/tester/test/file.img  /mnt/lp0  ext4  loop,rw,relatime  0  0
```

and rebooted.

(I did some tests by editing the line and running `sudo mount -a` until it worked.)

I verified with `df` that it works after rebooting,

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           382M  1.1M  381M   1% /run
/dev/sda9        32G  4.3G   26G  15% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      969M  2.5M  900M   1% /mnt/lp0
/dev/sda8       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           382M     0  382M   0% /run/user/1000
```

### Loop mount of general image file with [several] partitions

It is not straightforward to loop mount 'any' image file. I suggest that you use `kpartx` for that purpose. It can manage also images with [several] partitions. You find details how to use `kpartx` in [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347700/failed-to-read-last-sector-when-trying-to-mount-dd-file/1347723#1347723) to my answer to a question at AskUbuntu.

Comment: What you propose is very similar to what I have posted and may work for Ubuntu server, but not for ubuntu mate

Comment: @ajcg, In the title you asked about mounting and I think it works, meaning that *mounting* works as it should. It is the user interface that shows the mounted device twice. I am not using the MATE desktop environment, and cannot debug that part of your problem.

Comment: I think it is a bug. but maybe it isn't and it's just fstab issue. I do not know. Your answer is correct, just like what I posted, but it doesn't fix the problem. Anyway, I appreciate the effort you have put into my case.

Comment: @ajcg, I agree, it is probably a bug. Maybe the best way to manage it is the workaround that you describe in the question.